# Issue reading words from a file using Scanner class nextLine() method

Tags: java, input

I have a text file that contains collection of words from the English language.The words are written in alphabetical order with a single word on a line and with no empty lines , no punctuation etc . The list looks like as shown in the image below. The list continues till the last word starting from 'z' and there are no empty Lines whatsoever

[image: The list continues till the last word starting from 'z'. There are no empty Lines whatsoever]

I have made a simple program that reads words from this file line by line and writes the words on different files.The problem is that I am getting this error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0
>       at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
>       at sd.main(sd.java:27)

This could only happen if the nextLine() method returns an empty string in the line with the if condition.But I have no blank lines in the file from which I am reading.If I replace every instance of the nextLine() method with next() method within the program, it works flawlessly.Kindly enlighten me with the details causing this exception to occur.

```
  import java.io.* ;
  import java.util.*;

  public class sd {

  public static void main(String[] argue)  throws java.io.IOException {

     char incre = 97 ;
     File diction = new File("C:/Users/LoRd CuRZon/Desktop/dictionary/wordsEn.txt") ;
     PrintWriter alpha_list = new PrintWriter("C:/Users/LoRd CuRZon/Desktop/dictionary/a.txt") ;
     Scanner dictionary = new Scanner(diction) ;
     Scanner dictionarytemp = new Scanner(diction) ;

     while(dictionary.hasNextLine()) {

         if((char)incre != ((dictionarytemp.nextLine()).charAt(0)))  {      
            alpha_list.close();
            incre++ ;
            alpha_list = new PrintWriter("C:/Users/LoRd CuRZon/Desktop/dictionary/" + (char)incre + ".txt" ) ;
         }

     alpha_list.println(dictionary.nextLine());

      }

      alpha_list.close();
      dictionary.close();
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is you second `nextLine()` that is causing the problem. It moves to the next spot in the array. You do that twice per loop (in the while loop).

So if you change:

```
alpha_list.println(dictionary.nextLine());
```

to

```
alpha_list.println(incre);
```

You would run out of bound.